# Files under wwwroot path is not accessible

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

I have a functionality in my web application that let the users download some help documents by clicking on the document name. Recently I made a change in my project, I kept all the pdf files in my wwwroot folder instead of keeping them on some directory on the server. I kept them in the following hierarchy wwwroot > Assets > ConnectHelpDocuments. Now after deploying the application for some reason when I click on the file It says "Access to the path 'C:\Webs\Engage\API\wwwroot\Assets\ConnectHelpDocuments\xxxxx.pdf' is denied". It works fine on my localhost. Here's the code snippet that tries to read from the wwwroot and then send that as a file.

```
private const string ResourceDocument = @".\wwwroot\Assets\ConnectHelpDocuments\";

        [HttpGet("DownloadDocument/{fileName}")]
        [TypeFilter(typeof(AsyncUserActionFilter))]
        [System.Web.Mvc.ValidateInput(true)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadDocument(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(ResourceDocument, fileName);
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                    return NotFound();
                var memory = new MemoryStream();
                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
                }
                memory.Position = 0;
                return File(memory, GetContentType(filePath), fileName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.logger.LogError(ex.Message);
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

I am also attaching the screenshot of the project folder structure which shows the folders

[image]

Can anyone help me identify the reason? Is there any settings on the IIS that I need to tweak ? I don't have much access here otherwise I would have pasted the IIS settings as well.

Comment: Have you contained [wwwroot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57651856/iis-deployment-cannot-contains-files-for-wwwroot-folder-in-asp-net-core-2-2-razo) when publishing the project?

Comment: @YiyiYou No I haven't done that, let me try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you find a solution yet?

```
IWebHostEnvironment
WebRootPath
```

You can find the path of your file using the WebRootPath of IWebHostEnvironment. You will need to include this in your program/startup file. For example:

```
private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

public Startup
(
   IWebHostEnvironment environment
)
{
   _environment = environment;
}
```

And:

```
public class TestService : ITestService
{

   public static IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

   public TestService
   (
      IWebHostEnvironment environment
   )
   {
      _environment = environment;
   }

   private MemoryStream Attachment()
   {

      MemoryStream stream = new();

       try
       {

        string path = _environment.WebRootPath;
        path += "/Assets/ConnectHelpDocuments/Testfile.pdf";

        byte[] testByte = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

        stream = new(testByte, false);

      }
      catch (Exception exceptionTest)
      {
         Error_General(exceptionTest);
      }

      return stream;
   }
}
```

Also: please check whether your file properties is set to content. Otherwise it's not included in the publish.

Hope this helps.

Kind regards.